# Sharing a docking station between two computers

Tags: switch, docking-stations

I am looking for a way to share a docking station (with USB C output) between two computers, like a switch or something similar.
[image]

This is a diagram to illustrate my thought.

I have heard of KVM but it looks a bit expensive.

Is there such a switch that share a docking station between two computers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, but they are also expensive: https://a.co/20ROiKT