# Docking station for two computers simultaneously and both pc and mac

Tags: docking-stations

I’m looking for a docking station that satisfies these requirements:

- It should be possible to switch between attaching a pc laptop and a mac laptop. They should attach using the same cable, which should also provide power to the laptop.
- In addition to a laptop, the docking station should be connected permanently to a desktop computer. It should be possible to switch between the desktop computer and whatever laptop is attached by the push of a button. (If that requires a separate gadget, that’s okay).
- It should be possible to connect the usual peripherals.

All the equipment is no more than a couple of years old, except the desktop which is from 2015. Please let me know if more precise information is needed.

Comment: Also see this answer for a USB switch: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16527